# Reusing business logic for React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started learning React and I'm struggling to understand a good way to reuse a business logic between components.

For example, a have many forms submitting data. The workflow is always the same:

1. Fill in the data;
2. Clicks submit;
3. A snackbar is displayed with a loading message;
4. A network request is sent;
5. If the request is successful, then it displays a new snackbar with a success message and, in some cases, it redirects to a different route;
6. If the request returns an error, then it displays a snackbar with the error message.

I've created a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html):

```
function withSubmit(WrappedComponent, request, navigateTo) {
  return class extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        snackbar: null,
        navigate: null,
      };
    }

    updateSnackbar = snackbar => this.setState({ snackbar });

    handleSubmit = (...params) => {
      this.updateSnackbar('Loading...');

      // API request passed from the parent component to be called only after submitting a form.
      request(...params)
        .then(() => {
          this.updateSnackbar(navigateTo.msg);

          if (navigateTo.url) {
            this.setState({ navigate: navigateTo.url });
          }
        })
        .catch(err => this.updateSnackbar(err.message));
    };

    render() {
      const { navigate, snackbar } = this.state;

      return (
        <div>
          <WrappedComponent onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
          <Snackbar
            open={!!snackbar}
            message={snackbar}
          />
          { navigate ? <Redirect to={navigate} /> : null }
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
}
```

It works. However, it seems a bit complicated. Is there a simpler way to reuse that logic/flow?

Comment: you could use the react Context pattern (provider/consumer). or you can try using something like react-stamp to compose this kind of behavior.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure how the Context API would work for this case. I don't necessarily need to reuse data here. I actually just would like to reuse the whole flow (send a request/display a snackbar/redirect). So, when clicking on the submit button that flow would run.

Comment: the context value can be anything, even a function. or an object with methods. it simply becomes another prop on anything that consumes it. this way you can encapsulate all your submit/success/error logic and apply it to any component you want. another way is to use redux (specifically redux-thunk), but context is slightly more re-usable and lightweight